# How do I use postcss/autoprefixer in angular

Tags: angular, postcss, autoprefixer

I have read through the issue [#1521](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1512)

on how to use  postcss/autoprefixer I am still really unclear.

Do I just `npm install autoprefixer --save-dev`?
Is this the right way of doing it?

I have also read the postcss/autoprefixer docs I  still do not understand how to go about doing it

Please assist, thanks

**Update**
Using with SCSS, the script runs

```
postcss --parser postcss-scss -u autoprefixer --autoprefixer.browsers \"last 2 versions\" -r src/**/*.scss
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have installed the **postcss postcss-cli autoprefixer* as dev dependencies

```
npm install --save-dev postcss postcss-cli autoprefixer
```

And then create a npm script inside the package.json file to run the postcss cli and auto prefixer like so

```
"script": {
  ...
   "prefixcss": "postcss -u autoprefixer --autoprefixer.browsers 'last 2 versions' -r src/**/*.css",
  ...
}
```

And then ran the script before I rebuilt

```
 npm run prefixcss
```

Comment: hi Teebo, I was also looking for this solution and find only your answer clear enough to implement but when I ran npm run prefixcss I got > cross@1.1.0 prefixcss C:\PROJECTS\cross\weblisting
> postcss -u autoprefixer --autoprefixer.browsers 'last 2 versions' -r src/**/*.scss

TypeError: Patterns must be a string or an array of strings
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! cross@1.1.0 prefixcss: `postcss -u autoprefixer --autoprefixer.browsers 'last 2 versions' -r src/**/*.scss`
npm ERR! Exit status 1

Comment: @Simer are you working on Windows?

If so, try the following:
   postcss -u autoprefixer --autoprefixer.browsers \"last 2 versions\" -r src/**/*.css

Comment: If so, try:  

postcss -u autoprefixer --autoprefixer.browsers \"last 2 versions\" -r src/**/*.css

Comment: Thanks teebo. Yes I am using Windows. I will try this solution after reaching my workplace tomorrow. Will this work if I have scss file instead of css?  actually I am using angular 5 and want to see autoprefixer effect for IE browser. As I have used flexbox and grid layouts. But I have checked today that autoprefixer is already working in my project and prefixes does not really solve the issue. Have u ever encountered such issue for cross browser css? Thanks for ur time. :)

Comment: @Simer if  your files are scss then you need to install postcss-scss
 npm install --save-dev postcss-scss.

Yes I have come across such an issue, I usually go to the MS website and search, here is a link:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/?page=1&q=flexbox

search using keywords for your issue, and try also searching for solutions here in SO and other sites, do some search in here as well:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Backwards_Compatibility_of_Flexbox

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK starting Angular v11.2, PostCSS is already added to the angular cli. auto-prefixer is also enabled out of the box.

If you want to configure the PostCSS, just create a `postcss.config.js` file.

Comment: Where can I find that in the Angular docs?

Comment: @teebo Unfortunately there's no doc about that. But you can see the webpack configuration [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/src/webpack/configs/styles.ts). I also tested some CSS myself and it's working according to my `.browserslistrc` file.

Comment: I'm not sure about the `postcss.config.js` file though! I just read some post in Reddit about that.

Comment: OK I see, thanks for sharing