# How to change webpack.config file in angular project setup using angular cli

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, postcss

I have gone through [ultimate-angular-cli-reference](https://www.sitepoint.com/ultimate-angular-cli-reference/) and[#1656](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1656) to find answer to my question and few other articles. but still unclear.

My requirement: I want to run autoprefixer within angular app.

as per [How do I use postcss/autoprefixer in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48129327/how-do-i-use-postcss-autoprefixer-in-angular/48137374?noredirect=1#comment90244553_48137374) I just need to add autoprefixer script in my package.json and run script before running ng serve.

But what about webpack.config configuration which are given:

[autoprefixer github](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer#user-content-webpack)

Also is it ok if I use gulp or grunt for such tasks in angular cli projects?

I am using angular version 5 and Angular CLI: 6.0.8 (global)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot eject the configuration with Angular cli starting from version 6.
ng eject is temporarily disabled at v6.0.0.