# How can I prefix scss style files?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, sass

I tried to prefix my scss files, I found the autoprefixer but it only works with CSS, is there a method to make it work with scss files.

Autoprefixer commands:

```
npm install postcss-cli autoprefixer
npx postcss *.css --use autoprefixer -d build/
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Autoprefixer can be easily integrated with Sass and Stylus, since it runs after CSS is already compiled.

Reference: https://css-tricks.com/autoprefixer/

This [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48137374/1264804) explains how to use Autofixer in Angular and with scss files.

**Update:** This is the command to run  postcss/autoprefixer using scss.

`postcss --parser postcss-scss -u autoprefixer --autoprefixer.browsers \"last 2 versions\" -r src/**/*.scss`